# Can I use Pandas.apply method from index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create file from Pandas.DataFrame

1.txt  ,content is 'a'

2.txt  ,content is 'b'

3.txt  ,content is 'c'

4.txt  ,content is 'd'

5.txt  ,content is 'e'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
 'filename': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'sex': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

#I wanted to use apply method from index. but I coundn't find the index from apply Method
df["filename"].apply(lambda x: x.to_csv(df["filename"][x....])

# This doesn't work
for i in range(len(df["filename"])):
    df["filename"].iloc[[i],[1]].to_csv(f"{df.iloc[[i],[0]]}.txt")
```

How can I solve? Please give me advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should do what you want:

```
df.apply(lambda x: open('{}.txt'.format(x.filename), 'w').write(x.sex), axis=1)
```

Note you can't use .to_csv as this is a method of a DataFrame or Series. It can't be used on a string like 'a' or 'b'